# Dynamically evaluate conditional expression in r

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame

```
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
x2 <- c("a", "a", "c")
x3 <- c(10, 33, 45)
x <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3)

dimensions <- c("x1", "x2")
operators <- c(">", "==")
conditions <- c(1, "a")
```

Ideally, the output should be equivalent to the following expression in this case

```
x.filtered <- which(x$x1 > 1 & x$x2 == "a")
```

How do I dynamically setup and evaluate the expression above using "dimensions", "operators" and "conditions" vectors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help. `x.filtered <- which(x[dimensions[1]] > conditions[1] & x[dimensions[2]] ==conditions[2])`

Comment: Thanks!!! I managed to solve it using eval() and parse() functions. I have also posted the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possibility :

```
expr <- paste(dimensions, operators, conditions, collapse=" & ")
expr <- gsub("(?<=(= ))(\\w+\\b)", "'\\2'", expr, perl=T)
# or
expr <- gsub("(?<=(= ))([^0-9[:punct:]]+\\b)", "'\\2'", expr, perl=T)
filter <- eval(parse(text=expr), envir=x)
# then if you really need it you can use which
which(filter)
```

Comment: Could you please explain more on how the string replacement is being achieved in the second statement?

Comment: expr <- paste(dimensions, operators, "'",conditions, "'",collapse=" & ", sep = "")
eval(parse(text = expr), envir = x)
I tried this and seems to work well for now.

Comment: the goal was to put quotes around strings located after an "==" if they were not all numeric. @user2112376 it works fine but you can simplify it with  paste(dimensions, operators, sQuote(conditions), collapse=" & ") but you will probably have first to set useFancyQuotes=F to the options

Comment: I feel the adding of strings should not be based on the value of `conditions` but on the nature of the columns in `x`. Imagine if instead of `"a"` the OP wanted to extract `"1"`... Either way, I feel the OP should not cram his conditions into a vector but into a list so types (numeric, character) can be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some fiddling around, I found the solution to my problem

```
text1 = paste("x[", '"', dimensions[1],'"',"]", operators[1],'"',conditions[2],'"', sep="")
eval(parse(text = text1))
which(eval(parse(text = text1)))
```

I can use a loop and intersect() to iterate through each and every condition. Any other improvements on this solution are most welcome.

Hope this helps!!!